# Video Reader/Writer program xuggler not working

Tags: java, xuggler

I have downloaded Xuggler and added the Jar files to the Eclipse library, I wrote some code for java to get a flv file and convert it to mov:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader("res/input.flv");
        IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter("res/output.mov", reader);
        reader.addListener(writer);
        while(reader.readPacket() == null);
}}
```

My flv file is also in eclipse under a folder called res.

When I run this code I get these errors:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: could not open stream com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream@269225200[index:0;id:0;streamcoder:com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder@3536496[codec=com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec@269351856[type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO;id=CODEC_ID_H264;name=libx264;];time base=1/15;frame rate=0/0;pixel type=YUV420P;width=235;height=217;];framerate:0/0;timebase:1/90000;direction:OUTBOUND;]: Operation not permitted
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.openStream(MediaWriter.java:1192)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.getStream(MediaWriter.java:1052)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeVideo(MediaWriter.java:742)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeVideo(MediaWriter.java:783)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.onVideoPicture(MediaWriter.java:1434)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.AMediaToolMixin.onVideoPicture(AMediaToolMixin.java:166)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.dispatchVideoPicture(MediaReader.java:610)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.decodeVideo(MediaReader.java:519)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket(MediaReader.java:475)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

What do these errors mean and how do I fix them?

Comment: Also it may be worth mentioning, if I take the res/ out of the code the error becomes: could not open flv.

Answer (score 0):

We happen to use the exact same code in our labs and it always worked like a charm. In fact I copied your code to one of my Eclipse projects. I downloaded FLV files from the web and converted them successfully to MOV with your code.

My students often report problems with the project setup in conjunction with Xuggler. Perhaps you are willing to reconfigure your project to Maven which has never failed us so far. In the Maven dependencies platform related libraries are automatically added to the Eclipse project correctly.

As of the Kepler release the M2 module which is the Maven management for Eclipse is part of the mainline. Such that it should be easy to create a maven project. Just add the following repository and dependency to your pom.xml afterwards.

**Repositories:**

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>xuggle repo</id>
        <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Dependencies:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
        <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
        <version>5.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As mentioned before in a project setup like this your code is working. For your reference we tested on MacOS 10.9.4 and Java 7.